# Inspecting Element in Safari

Tags: macos, safari, inspect-element

I am using the latest iOS system for Mac, and have just finished completing all the updates.

I am trying to find the Developer Menu on the Mac, but I can't see it anywhere? Some have said if you just click Safari - Preferences there should be an option there, but I don't see it.

Any help would be hugely appreciated.

Thanks in advance

Kimberley

Answer (score 2):

Open the preferences, select the *"Advanced"* tab and check the *"Show Develop menu in menu bar"* checkbox at the bottom.

Comment: "Show Develop menu in the menu bar" doesn't exist

Answer (score -1):

try to minimize the screen of safari after that next to the APPLE logo you will see that file, edit, etc... also Develop tab in menu bar

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).